# What Node JS modules to use for developing admin dashboard and full audit trail for user activities?

Tags: cms, node.js

I have existing NodeJS app in which content author can create and update content with frontend UI being Vue JS app and backend is express Mongodb stack. Currently there is no user login. I want to add a few admin users with defined roles (manually adding such users in mongodb) and then add login UI so that only logged in author can now create/update content. What existing node modules to use for this ? Secondly I want to have complete audit trail of activities by logged in users such as content X was changed to X1 by user A then X1 was changed by user B to X2 etc. What node modules I can use for this purpose? Or CMS can help in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

In a user management system you have to take care of *authentication* and *authorization*.

While for authorization I think one could say there is an "accepted" go-to library for Node.js ([Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/)), I don't think there is a complete solution for what you need.

Actually, I was looking for the same thing a few weeks ago, and I found these projects:

- [Aqua](https://github.com/jedireza/aqua)
- [Frame](https://github.com/jedireza/frame)
- [Node-login](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login)
- [Ooth](https://github.com/nmaro/ooth)

I've never used any of these ones (yet), but I would try either Frame or Ooth. Aqua (formerly Drywall) seems no longer maintained, and Node-login is more a framework than a library.